# Apple Watchkit app and extension not installing on local watch

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I have a Watchkit app, but everytime I try installing I keep getting the failed to install error. I have followed all of apples docs and tech sheets and looked for an answer. My provisioning profile also appears to be correct. Any idea?

```
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[304] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder <LSApplicationProxy: 0x12d52e9f0> com.devglasses.iris
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[304] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Not creating progress for <LSApplicationProxy: 0x12d52e9f0> com.devglasses.iris since it is not a placeholder.
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone pkd[147] <Warning>: UNINSTALLED:com.devglasses.iris.watchkitextension com.devglasses.iris.watchkitextension(2.1.0) E2342D5F-E5FC-470E-BA39-DDA796CBE5E3 /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DCEE58B5-78C8-471C-B5AB-2D6679934757/Iris.app/PlugIns/Iris WatchKit Extension.appex
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone installd[47] <Notice>: 0x10050c000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Iris.app" type Developer requested by streaming_zip_conduit (pid 304)
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone installd[47] <Notice>: 0x10050c000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.devglasses.iris; Version=2.1.0, ShortVersion=2.1.0>
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone profiled[124] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone installd[47] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone profiled[124] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone installd[47] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone CLTM[20] <Error>: CLTM: _subscription 0x0, _subscribedChannels 0x0
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone installd[47] <Error>: resource modified: /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.sfYkm7/extracted/Iris.app/PlugIns/Iris WatchKit Extension.appex/Assets.car
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone installd[47] <Error>: 0x10050c000 -[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:]: 188: Failed to verify code signature of <MIPluginKitPluginBundle : path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.sfYkm7/extracted/Iris.app/PlugIns/Iris WatchKit Extension.appex identifier = com.devglasses.iris.watchkitextension type = 7> : 0xe8008017 (Signed resources have been added, removed, or modified)
Jun  2 12:27:51 SausageKings-iPhone installd[47] <Error>: 0x10050c000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed
Jun  2 12:27:52 SausageKings-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[304] <Error>: 0x10040c000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of <MIPluginKitPluginBundle : path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.sfYkm7/extracted/Iris.app/PlugIns/Iris WatchKit Extension.appex identifier = com.devglasses.iris.watchkitextension type = 7> : 0xe8008017 (Signed resources have been added, removed, or modified)" UserInfo=0x12d6227b0 {LibMISErrorNumber=-402620393, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=188, FunctionName=-[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of <MIPluginKitPluginBundle : path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.sfYkm7/extracted/Iris.app/PlugIns/Iris WatchKit Extension.appex identifier = com.devglasses.iris.watchkitextension type = 7> : 0xe8008017 (Signed resources have been added, removed, or modified)}
Jun  2 12:27:52 SausageKings-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[304] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Jun  2 12:27:52 SausageKings-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[304] <Warning>: __dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke:203: Failed to install application at file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Iris.app/ : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x12d6242f0 {Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620393, ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of <MIPluginKitPluginBundle : path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.sfYkm7/extracted/Iris.app/PlugIns/Iris WatchKit Extension.appex identifier = com.devglasses.iris.watchkitextension type = 7> : 0xe8008017 (Signed resources have been added, removed, or modified)}
```